# Loading GWT module in two and more HTML hosting pages

Tags: html, jsp, gwt

Does any one has an idea how to load same GWT module in two different HTML pages and if the script tag has to be modified or some thing like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy the script tag into each page you want to load the module.

If you need history support, you'll also have to copy that history iframe.  Any css files you link from the host page also need to be copied.

Addendum: If you try to access any elements by ID that are defined in your original host file, you also need to define those elements in the second host file.  For example, if you use RootPanel.get("specialDivName") to find a `<div id="specialDivName">` in the host page, you've got to make sure that div is in the second host page as well.

Comment: Actually i did, but it seems that I've a problem....here is some details.I use in that module text area that do some functionality in the events keyup and keydown(it takes some details from those events and put them in arraylist then the arraylist send those details to the sever which store them in JDO datastore),in fact that works fine when i use that text area once or more in the same HTML page but when i use those text areas on other pages nothing works or stored in the datastore even the one that works before....can you help me please figure that problem?

Comment: Looking at your other code, it seems like maybe you are depending on the structure of the html within the host page - see my update above.

Comment: Did yo mean that each id I access in my original host page must be accessed in any other host pages?